Flutter app with native exoplayer activity "restarts" the app on backpressed
I am having this weird bug where sometimes when I close my exoplayer activity inside of my flutter app it restarts the app. It just restarts the main flutter activity. Its weird.
MainActivity.Kt
package com.example.app

import android.util.Log
import android.content.Intent
import android.app.Activity
import android.os.Bundle
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.graphics.Color as AndroidColor

class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    private val CHANNEL = "com.example.app/video"

    companion object {
        private const val REQUEST_CODE_VIDEO_PLAYER = 1001
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        window.decorView.setBackgroundColor(AndroidColor.parseColor("#212121"))
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine!!.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            when (call.method) {
                "playUri" -> {
                    val uri = call.argument<String>("uri")
                    val watchedDuration = call.argument<Int>("watchedDuration")?.toLong() ?: 0L
                    if (uri != null) {
                        playUri(uri, watchedDuration)
                        result.success(null)
                    } else {
                        result.error("INVALID_ARGUMENT", "URI is null", null)
                    }
                }
                "getPosition" -> {
                    val position = MediaPlayerManager.getPosition()
                    result.success(position)
                }
                "getDuration" -> {
                    val duration = MediaPlayerManager.getDuration()
                    result.success(duration)
                }
                // "probeForNextEpisode" -> {
                //     val shouldShow = MediaPlayerManager.shouldShowNextEpisode()
                //     if (shouldShow) {
                //         MediaPlayerManager.showNextEpisodePrompt()
                //     }
                //     result.success(shouldShow)
                // }
                "cleanupPlayer" -> {
                    // MediaPlayerManager.release()
                    // result.success(null)
                }
                else -> result.notImplemented()
            }
        }
    }
    
    private fun playUri(uri: String, watchedDuration: Long) {
        val intent = Intent(this, VideoPlayerActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("uri", uri)
        intent.putExtra("watchedDuration", watchedDuration)
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_VIDEO_PLAYER)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        Log.d("MainActivity", "onActivityResult called with requestCode: $requestCode, resultCode: $resultCode")
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_VIDEO_PLAYER && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "VideoPlayerActivity returned")
            val watchedPosition = data?.getLongExtra("watchedPosition", 0L) ?: 0L
            val duration = data?.getLongExtra("duration", 0L) ?: 0L
            val nextEpisode = data?.getBooleanExtra("nextEpisode", false) ?: false

            val result = mapOf(
                "watchedPosition" to watchedPosition,
                "duration" to duration
            )

            // if (nextEpisode) {
            //     MethodChannel(flutterEngine!!.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL)
            //         .invokeMethod("findNextEpisode", null)
            // } else {
                MethodChannel(flutterEngine!!.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL)
                    .invokeMethod("onPlaybackCompleted", result)
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "onActivityResult called with unexpected requestCode or resultCode $resultCode $requestCode")
        }
    }
}

MediaPlayerManager.kt
// MediaPlayerManager.kt
package com.example.app

import android.content.Context
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.DialogInterface
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.view.KeyEvent
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.View
import android.view.WindowManager
import android.app.Dialog
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.media.AudioFocusRequest
import android.media.AudioManager
import android.media.AudioAttributes
import android.widget.*
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.TimeBar

//ExoPlayer
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayer
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.MediaItem
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.DefaultTrackSelector
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelectionOverride
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.C
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.TrackSelectionDialogBuilder
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.DefaultRenderersFactory
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecSelector
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Timeline

object MediaPlayerManager {
    var player: ExoPlayer? = null
    lateinit var playerView: PlayerView
    lateinit var audioManager: AudioManager
    lateinit var audioFocusRequest: AudioFocusRequest
    lateinit var trackSelector: DefaultTrackSelector
    lateinit var trackSelectionButton: ImageButton
    lateinit var subtitleSelectionButton: ImageButton

    //next episode prompt
    var nextEpisodeProgress: ProgressBar? = null
    var nextEpisodeView: View? = null
    var nextEpisodeHandler: Handler? = null
    var progressRunnable: Runnable? = null
    var progress = 0

    var promptedNextEpisode: Boolean = false
    var trackDialog: Dialog? = null
    var subtitleDialog: Dialog? = null
    var rootView: View? = null

    fun init(context: Context) {
        if (player == null) {
            audioManager = context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager

            trackSelector = DefaultTrackSelector(context)

            trackSelector.setParameters(
                trackSelector.buildUponParameters()
                    .setTunnelingEnabled(true)
                    .setTrackTypeDisabled(C.TRACK_TYPE_TEXT, true)
            )
            
            // Create a custom RenderersFactory
            val renderersFactory = DefaultRenderersFactory(context)
                .setMediaCodecSelector(MediaCodecSelector.DEFAULT)
                .setExtensionRendererMode(DefaultRenderersFactory.EXTENSION_RENDERER_MODE_ON)
                .setEnableDecoderFallback(true)
            
            player = ExoPlayer.Builder(context)
                .setRenderersFactory(renderersFactory)
                .setTrackSelector(trackSelector)
                .build()
        }
    }

    fun playUri(uri: String, context: Context, watchedDuration: Long = 0) {
        val audioAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MOVIE)
            .build()

        audioFocusRequest = AudioFocusRequest.Builder(AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN)
            .setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes)
            .setAcceptsDelayedFocusGain(true)
            .setOnAudioFocusChangeListener { }
            .build()

        val result = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(audioFocusRequest)
        if (result != AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
            println("Failed to obtain audio focus")
            return
        }

        playerView.visibility = View.VISIBLE // Show the PlayerView when the video starts

        val mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(Uri.parse(uri))
        player?.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
        player?.prepare()

            // Ensure subtitles remain disabled
        val parameters = trackSelector?.parameters?.buildUpon()
        ?.clearOverridesOfType(C.TRACK_TYPE_TEXT)
        ?.setTrackTypeDisabled(C.TRACK_TYPE_TEXT, true)
        ?.build()
        parameters?.let { trackSelector?.setParameters(it) }    

        if (watchedDuration > 0) {
            player?.seekTo(watchedDuration)
        }

        player?.play()
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Playing video with URI: $uri, starting from $watchedDuration ms")
    }

    fun shouldShowNextEpisode(): Boolean {
        return player != null && 
               !promptedNextEpisode && 
               getPosition() > 0 && 
               getDuration() > 0 &&
               (getPosition().toFloat() / getDuration().toFloat() > 0.95f)
    }
    fun release() {
        try {
            player?.let {
                try {
                    it.stop()
                    it.release() 
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Log.e("MainActivity", "Error releasing player", e)
                }
            }
            player = null

            try {
                audioManager.abandonAudioFocusRequest(audioFocusRequest)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("MainActivity", "Error abandoning audio focus", e)
            }

            try {
                trackDialog?.dismiss()
                subtitleDialog?.dismiss()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("MainActivity", "Error dismissing dialogs", e)
            }

            promptedNextEpisode = false
            
            // Clean up next episode resources
            try {
                nextEpisodeProgress?.progress = 0
                nextEpisodeProgress = null
                nextEpisodeView = null
                progressRunnable?.let { nextEpisodeHandler?.removeCallbacks(it) }
                nextEpisodeHandler = null
                progressRunnable = null
                progress = 0
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("MainActivity", "Error cleaning up next episode resources", e)
            }

            // Remove the PlayerView from the root view
            try {
                if (rootView?.parent != null) {
                    (rootView?.parent as? ViewGroup)?.removeView(rootView)
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("MainActivity", "Error removing root view", e)
            }

            try {
                playerView.visibility = View.GONE
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("MainActivity", "Error hiding player view", e)
            }

            Log.d("MainActivity", "Player resources cleaned up")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in release()", e)
        }
    }

    fun getPosition(): Long {
        return player?.currentPosition ?: 0
    }

    fun getDuration(): Long {
        return player?.duration ?: 0
    }
}


And videoPlayerActivity
package com.example.app

//colors
import android.graphics.Color as AndroidColor

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.DialogInterface
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.view.KeyEvent
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.View
import android.view.WindowManager
import android.app.Dialog
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.media.AudioFocusRequest
import android.media.AudioManager
import android.media.AudioAttributes
import android.widget.*
import android.util.Log
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.TimeBar

//ExoPlayer
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayer
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.MediaItem
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.DefaultTrackSelector
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelectionOverride
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.C
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.TrackSelectionDialogBuilder
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.DefaultRenderersFactory
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecSelector

//Animator
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter
import android.animation.Animator
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator

class VideoPlayerActivity : Activity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        window.decorView.setBackgroundColor(AndroidColor.parseColor("#212121"))

        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY or
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN or
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        )

        if (MediaPlayerManager.player == null) {
            MediaPlayerManager.init(this)

            MediaPlayerManager.rootView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null)
            MediaPlayerManager.playerView = MediaPlayerManager.rootView!!.findViewById(R.id.player_view)
            MediaPlayerManager.playerView.player = MediaPlayerManager.player
            MediaPlayerManager.playerView.useController = true
    
            // Add the next episode button view
            MediaPlayerManager.nextEpisodeView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.next_episode_button, null)
            MediaPlayerManager.nextEpisodeProgress = MediaPlayerManager.nextEpisodeView?.findViewById(R.id.nextEpisodeProgress)

            addContentView(
                MediaPlayerManager.rootView,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                )
            )

            addContentView(
                MediaPlayerManager.nextEpisodeView,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                ).apply {
                    gravity = android.view.Gravity.BOTTOM or android.view.Gravity.END
                    marginEnd = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.margin_96dp)
                    bottomMargin = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.margin_128dp)
                }
            )
    
            MediaPlayerManager.playerView.visibility = View.GONE

            MediaPlayerManager.nextEpisodeView?.visibility = View.GONE
            MediaPlayerManager.nextEpisodeView?.setOnClickListener {
                //playNextEpisode()
            }

            MediaPlayerManager.trackSelectionButton = MediaPlayerManager.rootView!!.findViewById(R.id.exo_track_selection)
            MediaPlayerManager.trackSelectionButton.setOnClickListener{
                if(MediaPlayerManager.trackDialog == null){
                    initPopupAudioTrackSelection()
                }
                MediaPlayerManager.trackDialog?.show()
            }

            MediaPlayerManager.subtitleSelectionButton = MediaPlayerManager.rootView!!.findViewById(R.id.exo_subtitle)
            MediaPlayerManager.subtitleSelectionButton.setOnClickListener{
                if(MediaPlayerManager.subtitleDialog == null){
                    initPopupSubtitleSelection()
                }
                MediaPlayerManager.subtitleDialog?.show()
            }

            // Play the video
            MediaPlayerManager.playUri(intent.getStringExtra("uri") ?: "", this, intent.getLongExtra("watchedDuration", 0L))
            
            // // Set up timer to check for next episode every 5 seconds
            // val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
            // handler.postDelayed(object : Runnable {
            //     override fun run() {
            //         val shouldShow = MediaPlayerManager.shouldShowNextEpisode()
            //         if (shouldShow) {
            //             showNextEpisodeButton()
            //         }
            //         handler.postDelayed(this, 5000) // Run again in 5 seconds
            //     }
            // }, 5000) // First run after 5 seconds

            // MediaPlayerManager.player?.addListener(object : Player.Listener {
            //     override fun onPlaybackStateChanged(state: Int) {
            //         if (state == Player.STATE_ENDED) {
            //             closePlayer()
            //         }
            //     }
            // })
        }
    }

    private fun showNextEpisodeButton() {
        MediaPlayerManager.promptedNextEpisode = true
        MediaPlayerManager.nextEpisodeView?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        MediaPlayerManager.nextEpisodeProgress?.progress = 0
    
        // Create smooth animation using ObjectAnimator
        val progressAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(
            MediaPlayerManager.nextEpisodeProgress,
            "progress",
            0,
            100
        ).apply {
            duration = 5000 // 5 seconds
            interpolator = LinearInterpolator() // Makes the animation run at a constant rate
            addListener(object : AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator) {
                    Log.d("VideoPlayer", "Animation ended, attempting to close player")
                    runOnUiThread {
                        try {
                            if (!isFinishing) {
                                Log.d("VideoPlayer", "Calling closePlayer")
                                closePlayer(nextEpisode = true)
                            } else {
                                Log.d("VideoPlayer", "Activity already finishing")
                            }
                        } catch (e: Exception) {
                            Log.e("VideoPlayer", "Error closing player", e)
                            finish()
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    
        progressAnimator.start()
    }

    private fun initPopupAudioTrackSelection() {
        val mappedTrackInfo = MediaPlayerManager.trackSelector.currentMappedTrackInfo ?: return

        val audioRenderer = (0 until mappedTrackInfo.rendererCount)
            .firstOrNull { mappedTrackInfo.getRendererType(it) == C.TRACK_TYPE_AUDIO }
            ?: return

        val trackSelectionDialogBuilder = TrackSelectionDialogBuilder(
            this,
            "Audio Track Selector", 
            MediaPlayerManager.player!!,
            audioRenderer
        ).setTheme(R.style.DarkDialogTheme)

        MediaPlayerManager.trackDialog = trackSelectionDialogBuilder.build()
    }

    private fun initPopupSubtitleSelection() {
        // Initialize dialog lazily only once
        if (MediaPlayerManager.subtitleDialog != null) {
            return
        }

        val dialog = Dialog(this)
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.subtitle_selection_dialog)
        dialog.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
        dialog.window?.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

        val titleTextView = dialog.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.dialogTitle)
        titleTextView.text = "Select Subtitles"
        titleTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)

        val listView = dialog.findViewById<ListView>(R.id.subtitleListView)
        val subtitleOptions = mutableListOf<Pair<String, TrackSelectionOverride?>>()
        val adapter = object : ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mutableListOf()) {
            override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
                val view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent)
                val textView = view.findViewById<TextView>(android.R.id.text1)
                textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)

                val currentOverrides = MediaPlayerManager.trackSelector.parameters.overrides
                val isCurrentSelection = when {
                    position == 0 -> MediaPlayerManager.trackSelector.parameters.getRendererDisabled(getSubtitleRenderer() ?: return view)
                    else -> currentOverrides.any { (_, override) ->
                        override == subtitleOptions[position].second
                    }
                }

                if (isCurrentSelection) {
                    view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.muted_green))
                } else {
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
                }

                return view
            }
        }
        listView.adapter = adapter

        listView.setOnItemClickListener { _, _, position, _ ->
            val selection = subtitleOptions[position].second
            val parameters = MediaPlayerManager.trackSelector.parameters.buildUpon()
            if (selection == null) {
                parameters.setTrackTypeDisabled(C.TRACK_TYPE_TEXT, true)
            } else {
                parameters.setTrackTypeDisabled(C.TRACK_TYPE_TEXT, false)
                parameters.clearOverridesOfType(C.TRACK_TYPE_TEXT)
                parameters.addOverride(selection)
            }
            MediaPlayerManager.trackSelector.parameters = parameters.build()
            dialog.dismiss()
        }

        dialog.setOnShowListener {
            // Only populate options when dialog is shown
            subtitleOptions.clear()
            subtitleOptions.add(Pair("Off", null))

            val mappedTrackInfo = MediaPlayerManager.trackSelector.currentMappedTrackInfo
            val subtitleRenderer = getSubtitleRenderer()

            if (mappedTrackInfo != null && subtitleRenderer != null) {
                val trackGroups = mappedTrackInfo.getTrackGroups(subtitleRenderer)
                for (groupIndex in 0 until trackGroups.length) {
                    val group = trackGroups[groupIndex]
                    for (trackIndex in 0 until group.length) {
                        val format = group.getFormat(trackIndex)
                        val label = "${format.label ?: "Unknown"} (${format.language ?: "Unknown"})"
                        subtitleOptions.add(Pair(label, TrackSelectionOverride(group, listOf(trackIndex))))
                    }
                }
            }

            adapter.clear()
            adapter.addAll(subtitleOptions.map { it.first })
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        MediaPlayerManager.subtitleDialog = dialog
    }

    private fun getSubtitleRenderer(): Int? {
        val mappedTrackInfo = MediaPlayerManager.trackSelector.currentMappedTrackInfo ?: return null
        return (0 until mappedTrackInfo.rendererCount)
            .firstOrNull { mappedTrackInfo.getRendererType(it) == C.TRACK_TYPE_TEXT }
    }
    
    private fun toggleSubtitles() {
        val mappedTrackInfo = MediaPlayerManager.trackSelector.currentMappedTrackInfo ?: return
        val subtitleRenderer = (0 until mappedTrackInfo.rendererCount)
            .firstOrNull { mappedTrackInfo.getRendererType(it) == C.TRACK_TYPE_TEXT }
            ?: return
    
        val parameters = MediaPlayerManager.trackSelector.parameters.buildUpon()
        val isCurrentlyDisabled = MediaPlayerManager.trackSelector.parameters.getRendererDisabled(subtitleRenderer)
    
        parameters.setRendererDisabled(subtitleRenderer, !isCurrentlyDisabled)
        MediaPlayerManager.trackSelector.parameters = parameters.build()
    }

    private var backPressedTime: Long = 0
    private val backPressedInterval: Long = 2000 // 2 seconds

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (MediaPlayerManager.playerView.isControllerVisible) {
            MediaPlayerManager.playerView.hideController()
            return
        }

        val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        if (currentTime - backPressedTime < backPressedInterval) {
            closePlayer()
        } else {
            backPressedTime = currentTime
            Toast.makeText(this, "Press back again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    // // Add these lifecycle methods
    // override fun onPause() {
    //     super.onPause()
    //     MediaPlayerManager.player?.pause()
    // }

    // override fun onStop() {
    //     super.onStop()
    //     MediaPlayerManager.player?.pause()
    // }

    private fun closePlayer(nextEpisode: Boolean = false) {
        Log.d("VideoPlayer", "closePlayer called with nextEpisode: $nextEpisode")
        try {
            val intent = Intent()
            val watchedPosition = MediaPlayerManager.getPosition()
            val duration = MediaPlayerManager.getDuration()
            intent.putExtra("watchedPosition", watchedPosition)
            intent.putExtra("duration", duration)

            if (nextEpisode) {
                intent.putExtra("nextEpisode", true)
            }

            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)

            MediaPlayerManager.release()

            super.onBackPressed()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("VideoPlayer", "Error in closePlayer", e)
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
}


Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I had Finish() inplace of super.onBackPressed() originally and it made no difference. I have tried commenting out all the communication code and still the same error. Also you can see I commented out any other stop or end functionality and the result is the same. The bug only happens sometimes, probably 50/50 chance. Thanks!
